# Lottery Ticket Hypothesis - Iterative Pruning

Tags: neural-network

I was reading about [The Lottery Ticket Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03635.pdf) and it was mentioned in the paper:

> we focus on iterative pruning, which repeatedly trains, prunes, and
>   resets the network over n rounds; each round prunes (p^(1/n))% of the
>   weights that survive the previous round.

Can someone please explain this say for each round with numbers, when n = 5 (rounds) and the final sparsity desired (p) = 70%.

In this example, the numbers I computed are as follows:

```
Round        (p^(1/n))% of weights pruned

1             0.93114999

2             0.86704016

3             0.80734437

4             0.75175864

5             0.7
```

According to these calculations, it seems that the first round prunes 93.11% (approx) of the weights, whereas, the fifth round prunes 70% of the weights. It's as if as the rounds progress, the percentage of weights being pruned decreases.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using p^(1/n). As you increase n after each iteration, your p^(1/n) term decreases!